# Unable to fetch the exact date value from excel cell

Tags: excel, c#-4.0

I am fetching the value present in the excel cell which is a date like 20-3-2004 using the following code:

```
string logResult = null;
string ResultFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + ResultFile;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application myapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = myapp.Workbooks.Open(ResultFilePath);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

var cell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[row, col];
logResult = cell.Value.ToString();
```

but in the logresult I am always getting date in format 20/3/2004 . please suggest how get the exact format of the date which is written in the cell.

Comment: cell.Value.ToString("dd-M-yyyy")

Comment: Is this the only way steve? I mean i don't want to pass any argument if there exists some other way around.

Comment: The DateTime.ToString() method without parameters creates a string representation of the value of the current datetime object according to the general date and time format specifier ('G'). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf.aspx If you want a different formatting then you could change your international settings in every machine where your program runs (?) or apply a formatting parameter

Answer (score 0):

A date value has no format. It is the code that you use to display it that present that value is some form on video.

In your case, it is the ToString() call that trasform whatever has been read on the cell in a string. If it is a date then it trasform it according to the current international settings of your machine.

You could force the ToString() method to use a particular format applying a Format Mask parameter like

```
 logResult = cell.Value.ToString("d-M-yyyy");
```

See the topic on MSDN about [DateTime.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx)